# How to make an object copy scale from another object in one direction?

Tags: animation, scale

So I have a square object. I want to make it scaled narrower but by using "other" object as guide. So when I rotate that other object the direction of the scaling of the  square changes to the axis the other object is pointing towards? So If rotate the other object 45 degrees the scaling axis also changes by 45 which causes the square to be skewed of sorts. But the main object doesn't rotate.

How do I do this (drivers, constraints, modifiers? I want to animate this so I need individual control of both rotation and scaling direction but I can't get the scaling direction to work no matter what. Below is an example image and sample file.

how I want the square scaling to change as I rotate the scaled round arrow object:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOhFU.png
link to blend file:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/72wjclt55kmlg3b/copy_scale_rot.zip/file

So the scale rotates with the round object but rotation is not copied.  There is a similar question asked in 2017 but that does something weird with the scaling and the result is not scaled into one direction but sort of second scaling added into one direction that rotates...

Comment: The answer is to use a Transformation constraiint. It gives you considerable control over how to map a transformation of one object to a different transformation of another object.

Comment: I'm, going to need litte more info than that. How do you get the scaling direction to follow the control object orientation/rotation?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your goal. What the transformation constraing would allow is for, say your control object's rotation X to drive a receiver object's Scale Y, for example. But what you seem to want is more complex than that. Sorry if I weighted in prematurely.